# Spring Data - Custom query: count and list

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm having difficulties generate an object to provide me data based on two tables.

### Table One

```
public class User {
    private String name;
//...
}
```

### Table Two

```
public class Profile {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

### Objective

I need an object to give me the name and number of per user profiles.

Something like (in JSON):

```
[
    {"name":"John", "profiles":1 },
    {"name":"Maria", "profiles":5 },
    {"name":"Victor", "profiles":3 }
]
```

**The best solution to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a bean that will be used to generate your Json:

```
public class ABean {
    private String name;
    private Integer profiles;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then, your spring data jpa query would look like this:

```
SELECT new ABean(p.user.name, count(p.id)) FROM Profile p JOIN p.user GROUP BY p.user.name
```